# Is there a telegraf plugin which reads snmptraps from manager?

Tags: snmp, grafana, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

Is there a telegraf plugin which reads snmptraps from snmp manager

Thanks,
Simhadri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Just came to this question, and in the meantime there is already for a long time the [snmp_trap](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/snmp_trap) input plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no plugin available to listen snmptraps in telegraf. It is an open feature(https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/issues/4377).

But we have a perl implementation for snmp traps listener, for more you can refer below url
https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMPTrapd

Thanks,
simhadri